# How to restore hudson configuration?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I had Hudson running via:

```
cd /usr/lib/hudson
java -jar hudson.war
```

Unfortunately, I restarted that server and on accessing the Hudson Url, I found that all the configuration is missing.

However, I can see that all the configuration files were saved under `~/.hudson`  How can I start it so it recognizes the already-existing config?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Apparently there was already an instance of Hudson booting automatically with the default configuration.  I killed the existing instance, restarted the new service using `java -jar hudson.war` and the configuration was restored.  I also set the environment variable HUDSON_HOME to `/home/user_name/.hudson`, but I don't think that would've made a difference in this case.